# Constraint Violation Property Path when using Sets

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

I can't get my mind to wrap around a problem I have with a requirement concerning JSR303 bean validation (I'm currently using Hibernate Validator).

Assuming I have the following domain model

```
class Foo {
   private Set<Bar> bars = new HashSet<>();

   @Valid
   public Set<Bar> getBars() { ... }
}

class Bar {
   private String name;

   @NotBlank
   public String getName() { ... }
}
```

Say I have a `foo` instance with two `bar`s with one of the two names being empty.  After validating `foo` I'm holding a `@NotBlank` constraint violation with a property path `bars[].name` in my hand. Which is all well, but...

is there any way I can find out which of the two bars had its name empty? Or am I forced to use a `List` here and introspect the - then unique - property path using reflection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest release of Hibernate Validator, [5.2.0.CR1](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/First52CandidateReleaseHibernateValidator520CR1), provides a [solution](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-extensions-path-api) for this. You can unwrap property path nodes and get the property value. That way you know which `Bar` instance is affected:

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<Foo>> constraintViolations = ...;

Path path = constraintViolations.iterator().next().getPropertyPath();
Iterator<Path.Node> nodeIterator = path.iterator();

Path.Node node = nodeIterator.next();
Bar bar = (Bar) node.as( PropertyNode.class ).getValue();
```

Comment: Sigh, that *would* be exactly what I need! Unfortunately I can't update to Hibernate Validator 5.2.0.CR1 just yet, because its not released yet (company policies). I guess I have to stick with `List`s for now. +1 for pointing out the bright new future.